# How can I use files in one project to create a library in another project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a standalone project that contains some code I'd like to re-used.  I created a library project in order to contain that code.  There does not appear to be a way to move files from the one project to the other. (cut/paste in solution explorer did not work)

I then manually copied the files in Windows explorer (outside of VS) into the library's main "folder" but they didn't show up in solution explorer either.

Anyone know of a way to do this without having to manually create each file in the library and then copying/pasting the code into the files?

Comment: you have to click show all files files in the explorer then right click on the file and select include in project

Comment: If you want to put this as a solution, I'll wait for a more "elegant" one for a few days but will accept yours if nothing else pops up.  (Meaning one that doesn't require Windows explorer file manipulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the files and paste them into your solution/project folder(s). Once the files physically exist within your solution/project folder structure (Windows FileSystem / Explorer), then you right-click on your project within Visual Studio, select `Add` then `Existing Item`. Browse to the location of that file and open it. It will now exist within your project as a code file.

If you have two projects within the same solution, you can simply drag the file from one project to the other within Visual Studio Solution Explorer. That will create a copy of the class in the new project. You can then remove the old one and clean up any code references in the first project.